# BLE Frequent disconnection and not connecting automatically when in range

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

Hi i am developing an app to read heart rate from bracelet (Band) and displaying in application using bluetooth but the bluetooth connection is getting disconnected frequently and also not connecting automatically when in range. Any reference please.

Comment: Can you post any code reference? or method of connection?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android you should look for Bluetooth Auto Connect app which connects near by bluetooth device automatically

can be found here

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.myklos.btautoconnect&hl=en

Comment: You can use NXP ble device with available demo code that works..https://dzone.com/articles/building-the-nxp-ble-stack-with-open-source-gnu-an